# List available (downloaded) languages in Linux?

Tags: linux, locale

How can we see which languages are available to use in the Linux terminal (i.e. already downloaded)?

I read [that English is always available](https://askubuntu.com/a/142814/906745), but I am not sure which other languages are available (without downloading them - i.e. currently installed), nor do I know how to list them.

Answer (score 3):

This command can be used to display a list of all available locales:

```
locale -a
```

See `locale`'s [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locale.1.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l /usr/share/locale/
```

It does not mean that all apps are supported in all languages, you might need to install additional localization package for particular app or desktop environment.